# Display links with access only

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there any way how to display only links with access, which is defined by

```
[Authorize(Roles = "SomeRole")]
```

In controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe that there is a simple solution for doing this without reflecting the `Controller`, getting the `Action` and checking the `AuthorizationFilters`.

With that said, an alternative solution might be to create an extension method overload for `Html.ActionLink` which takes a role name and check `User.IsInRole(roleName)`. Only output a link if the user has access to the specified role.

Something like this:

```
public static class EntentionMethods
{
    public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(this HtmlHelper helper, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, string roleName)
    {
        if (!helper.ViewContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole(roleName))
        {
            return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
        }

        return helper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, controllerName);
    }
}
```

Not a pretty as you might have been hoping, but this often serves the needs.

Answer (score 1):

The Authorize attribute should be placed on the controller actions (or controller itself) in which you want to restrict access to, this way you are enforcing only users with the role of "somerole" to access the links generated to and from the controller actions. The links you want to restrict access to will not be displayed from the Authorize attribute. It simply restricts and enforces users in roles, or users with certain names to access the actions, if roles and users are explicitly defined.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use [MvcSiteMapProvider](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider) for your menu. It has a built-in [security trimming](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Security-Trimming) feature that automatically hides links according to AuthorizeAttribute. If you don't like the built-in HTML helpers, you can customize the templates and/or build your own HTML helpers that hide links based on node accessibility.

Or, if you don't want to use a 3rd party library, you can reverse engineer the [AuthorizeAttributeAclModule](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/blob/master/src/MvcSiteMapProvider/MvcSiteMapProvider/Security/AuthorizeAttributeAclModule.cs) to make your own implementation.

**Full Disclosure**

I am a major contributor of MvcSiteMapProvider.