# Hide ActionLinks based on user roles without exposing roles in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, authorization, actionlink

I use the AuthorizeAttribute and roles (Identity). I want to hide ActionLinks based on user roles. I found solutions with HtmlHelpers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9729865/display-links-with-access-only). But I really don't like those solutions because the view must know about the required roles. This means the roles are defined twice: in the controller and the view.

Does anyone know a better solution? Can I e.g. get the roles from the AuthorizeAttribute in the view or in the controller (maybe use ViewBag to transfer to view). I thougt about reflections, but this is bad when it comes to performance as the controller code is executed for every request.

The nicest solution would be without logic in the view anyway..

Comment: I don't think that is possible, you gotta have the if statements in the views

Comment: Why don't you use a view-model or ViewBag property to express the fact the view has to show all links or hide some? If you don't want to do this you can have 2 views and decide which to load in controller but this way you duplicate code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to use [MvcSiteMapProvider](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider) for your menu. It has a built-in [security trimming](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Security-Trimming) feature that automatically hides links according to AuthorizeAttribute. If you don't like the built-in HTML helpers, you can customize the templates and/or build your own HTML helpers that hide links based on node accessibility.

Or, if you don't want to use a 3rd party library, you can reverse engineer the [AuthorizeAttributeAclModule](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/blob/master/src/MvcSiteMapProvider/MvcSiteMapProvider/Security/AuthorizeAttributeAclModule.cs) to make your own implementation.

**Full Disclosure**

I am a major contributor of MvcSiteMapProvider.